# Where can I find the honeywell libraries to interact with Dolphin 6100 device?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-ce, smart-device

I have to create an application for Honeywell Dolphin 6100 ; a mobile computer with a barcode scanner that uses Windows CE 5.0 like OS.

But I can not the find the relative librairies to make the interraction with the barcode scanner and the keyboard possible .

Does any one know any link that can help to find these librairies and may be some tutoriels that worked with the device ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple search with a web search engine for "Dolphin 6100 SDK" turned up as the first result (with both Google and Bing) [the Honeywell page for the device](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=&cat=&pid=Dolphin6100&rank=&=). Clicking on the "Software" tab on that page gets me a list with SDK v1.03 at the very top.